# Can anyone explain how to do this number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$ be real numbers such that $x, y, z, x+y, y+z, z+x$ are all non-zero, and such that $\frac{xy}{x+y} , \frac{yz}{y +z} , \frac{zx}{z +x}$ are integers (i.e. belong to $\mathbb Z$).

Show that $x,y,z$ are rational numbers (i.e. belong to $\mathbb Q$).

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

We can write $P=\dfrac{xy}{x+y}\implies \dfrac1P=\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y$ where $P$ is some integer

Comment: so its the same for the other fractions right?

Comment: @akshay, Yes:) Then we can find $\dfrac1x$

Comment: I cannot find 1/x :( in terms of the intergers. can you help please?

Comment: @akshay, We have three equations with three unknowns , right?

Comment: right. I got it now. I did some wrong calculation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\frac {xy}{x+y}, b=\frac {yz}{y+z}, c=\frac {zx}{z+x}$ where a,b,c are integers. Now $$\frac 1a=\frac 1x+\frac 1y=r_1 and \frac 1b=\frac 1y+\frac 1z=r_2 and \frac 1c=\frac 1z+\frac 1x=r_3$$ Here $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are rationals since a,b,c are integers. Therefore $$\frac 1x=\frac {r_1+r_2+r_3}2-r_2=\frac {r_1-r_2+r_3}2$$. this shows that $\frac 1x$ is a rational number and hence x is also a rational number. Similarly you can prove for y and z.